# How to return JSON response when an Item changes in MongoDB using NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a NodeJS server and mongoDB where I have get and post API for the data. And I was wondering if I want to change something for example in my `Users` collection and have the changes directly send to my frontend react project. I was reading about socket-io, and can't find how to send the data as I am sending it in the API.

Is there any resources or examples on this ?

Comment: You may be interested in https://debezium.io or https://guide.meteor.com/  - however, my best advice is to actually think whether your app *needs* reactivity, and how it relates to the front-end. Will users see each other's changes? What if they decide to work on the same document at the same time? Should they be able to update one another's forms? Should they block?

Comment: You can use socket.io and watch for changes in [https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/)